# Ruby local_variable keeps referenced to @instance_variable

Tags: ruby, pointers

```
class Foo
  def bar
    @instance_variable = [['first']]

    # make a duplicate object with the :dup method
    local_variable=@instance_variable.dup

    # They have different object_id
    p @instance_variable.object_id
    p local_variable.object_id


    local_variable.each{|n|n.push('second')}
    @instance_variable
  end
end

f=Foo.new
p f.bar

=> 2000
=> 2002
=> [["first", "second"]]
```

It seems that the local_variable still references to the @instance_variable, although it is a different object. This behaviour is both with the `push` and `unshift` in the each block. With a normal assignment like `local_variable='second'`, the result is as expected `=> [['first']]`

I don't understand why `local_variable.each{|n|n.push('second')}` has an effect on the `@instance_variable`

Using Ruby-1.9.2p318

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `local_variable` and `@instance_variable` have references to the same object, the inner array `['first']`. And because it's a mutable Array, you can effect changes to one array through the other.

`Object#dup` in Ruby [provides a shallow copy](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-dup). In order to make a deep copy of an Array, you'd need to write some code (or find a library) that recursively walks the data structure, deep-cloning its pieces of mutable state.

Comment: The easy way to do a deep copy is to marshal and unmarshal the array. That will completely reconstruct the object graph, assuming everything in there is amenable to marshaling (not every object necessarily is).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're not testing the right object. You say:

```
p @instance_variable.object_id
p local_variable.object_id
```

But that's not the object you're going to push onto. Try this instead:

```
p @instance_variable[0].object_id
p local_variable[0].object_id
```

They *are* the same object.

In other words, it is *not* the case that changing `local_variable` changes `@instance_variable`, but it just so happens that they both *contain* a reference to the same object, so obviously changing *that* object as pointed to by one changes that object as pointed to by the other.